# How to run servlet 3.0 in websphere 7

Tags: websphere-7, ibm-was

how to run Servlet 3.0 app in WebSphere 7?

I know WebSphere 7 support Servlet 2.5, but I don't know if is impossible or possible.

Comment: Upgrade to WebSphere 8.x or WebSphere Liberty.

Comment: It's the only way? My company don't wont upgrade now.

Comment: Yes, that's the only way. WAS 7 supports Java EE 5, Servlet 3.0 is Java EE 6, so you need server compliant with Java EE 6. Or downgrade your app to 2.5. What feature of 3.0 do you require?